# R: Use rollapply on list column

Tags: r, zoo, purrr

I have a data frame `df` with a `dates` column and a `values` column and want to calculate the 5% quantile of `values` for the past `n` days for every date in `dates`. The problem is that the dates do not appear uniquely and in different (random) cardinalities. For example

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

n <- 3

dates_v <- seq(as_date("2018-09-01"), as_date("2018-09-14"), by = "days") 

df <- data.frame(dates = rep(dates_v,c(3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 3, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3)), 
                 values = rep(seq(1,5),8))
```

I can write a for loop that solves this problem, but this is quite slow:

```
df2 <- list()

for (k in dates_v[n:length(dates_v)]) {
  k <- as_date(k)

  df2 <- c(df2,
  df %>%
    filter(dates >= k %m-% days(n-1) & dates <= k) %>%
    mutate(dates = k) %>%
    group_by(dates) %>%
    summarise(values = quantile(values, 0.05)) %>%
    list())
}

df2 <- df2 %>%
  bind_rows()
```

I tried the `zoo` package, but the `rollapply` functions do not seem to be applicable here due to the varying window sizes. One idea I had was to transform the `values` column into a nested column using `purrr::nest` and then use `rollapply` to roll-concatenate the entries of the nested column

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, unlist))

df2$data <- rollapply(df2$data, width = n, c, align = "right")

df2 %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~quantile(., 0.05)))
```

but that did not work out. Is there something I am doing wrong, or is `rollapply` simply not working with list columns?

**Edit:**

A more realistic example for my use case is a data frame of the form

```
dates_v <- seq(as_date("2018-01-01"), as_date("2018-09-14"), by = "days") 

df <- data.frame(dates = rep(dates_v,sample(seq(9000,11000), length(dates_v), replace = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(values = rnorm(length(dates)))
```

Comment: Added for loop that calculates output (`df2`) that I would like to obtain faster using `zoo` and `purrr`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a loop you can use `sapply` like this:

```
n <- 3
sapply(unique(df$dates), function(x){
                        quantile(df$values[df$dates >= x - (n-1) & df$dates <= x], 0.05)
                      })
  5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5%   5% 
1.10 1.20 1.00 1.30 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.40 1.30 1.35 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
```

To get it into a data.frame you could do this:

```
outcome <- data.frame(dates = unique(df$dates),
                      quantiles = sapply(unique(df$dates), function(x){
                        quantile(df$values[df$dates >= x - (n-1) & df$dates <= x], 0.05)
                      })
                      )
        dates quantiles
1  2018-09-01      1.10
2  2018-09-02      1.20
3  2018-09-03      1.00
4  2018-09-04      1.30
5  2018-09-05      1.00
6  2018-09-06      1.00
7  2018-09-07      1.00
8  2018-09-08      1.40
9  2018-09-09      1.30
10 2018-09-10      1.35
11 2018-09-11      1.00
12 2018-09-12      1.00
13 2018-09-13      1.00
14 2018-09-14      1.00
```

Comment: For the more realistic example that I have added in an edit above, your approach takes about 6s, whereas my for loop needs about 8s. I am, however, primarily curious as to whether this can be done using `rollapply`, possible in conjuction with `purrr`.

Comment: @guzbrush, I'm not sure why you are fixated on zoo and purrr. If you want extra speed, data.table or rcpp might be better to look at.

Comment: I am not really fixed on zoo and purrr, just interested in whether you can use rollapply to rollconcatenate list columns. Perhaps I should have posed this question without the motivating problem, but at least from the title it should be clear in what I am interested. I would like to have extra speed, but I have not yet worked with data.table or rcpp and do not have time to dive into them now. Hence rollapply, which I hoped would be applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

`rollapply` can be used with varying widths by specifying a vector of widths, `w`, one per element.  `r` gives the quantiles for all rows from the first dates-2 row to the current row and the last line of code drops rows having dates which are not the last occurrence of that date and also drops the `value` column.

```
w <- seq_along(df$dates) - match(df$dates - 2, df$dates, nomatch = 0)
r <- transform(df, `5%` = rollapplyr(values, w, quantile, 0.05), 
  check.names = FALSE)

r[!duplicated(df$dates, fromLast = TRUE), -2]
```

giving:

```
        dates   5%
3  2018-09-01 1.10
5  2018-09-02 1.20
6  2018-09-03 1.20
10 2018-09-04 1.25
11 2018-09-05 1.20
16 2018-09-06 1.00
17 2018-09-07 1.25
20 2018-09-08 1.35
23 2018-09-09 1.25
25 2018-09-10 1.30
30 2018-09-11 1.40
33 2018-09-12 1.00
37 2018-09-13 1.00
40 2018-09-14 1.40
```

or with pipes and using `w` from above:

```
df %>%
   mutate(`5%` = rollapplyr(.$values, w, quantile, 0.05)) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(.$dates, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
   select(-values)
```

Comment: I have added a more realistic example for my use case in an edit. Using this data frame I get an out of memory error with your approach. Basically, in order for your approach to work for my use case, I think that, in addition to being able to specify varying window widths, one would have to be able to tell `rollapply` to work on only a subset of all available rows.

Comment: That really seems to be a different problem. You no longer have sequential dates.  Now the dates are unsorted and there are missing dates.

Comment: The column `dates` of `df` as defined in the edit of the question contains all days between 2018-01-01 and 2018-09-14 in increasing order, but every day repeated by a random number between 9000 and 11000. This will be ~2.500.000 rows. Your approach calculates the quantiles for every row in the dataframe, whereas it would suffice (and be much more efficient) if the quantiles could be calculated only for the 257 rows with row numbers `c(which(diff(df$dates)!=0), nrow(df))`

Comment: You could use a width of 0 or 1, say, for the rows you don't want and possibly test for those lengths in the function to skip processing.  That might speed it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this both with 0s and 1s and now there is no out-of-memory error, but it takes ~7mins to run, as opposed to the ~6s using phiver's sapply solution.

Comment: Clearly that is a better solution for your size of problem.  I think the benefit of `rollapply` is that it allows simple specification of a range of problems relatively easily.

Comment: I am not sure if this use case is sufficiently common to warrant new features but one idea would be to enhance rollapply to allow NAs in the width vector for components that are not to be processed or returned.

Comment: Behind this question is the need to find thresholds for every day that ensure that the continuous scores of a classifier that gets retrained daily are binned into buckets of approximately same proportions. The thresholds are obtained as the quantiles of the scores of the past `n` days. More exactly, this is for a shiny app which allows one to compare the bucketing for different choices of `n` and quantile levels. I am also not sure if this problem is common enough to justify incorporating the feature that you mentioned, but I would certainly welcome it.